# Can't retrive data from firebase firestore and show it in View Text in android studio

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

The data is already saved on the Firestore but I can't get it. Also, the created list size is still equal to null.
I know I suppose to get data from `existUserProfileModelList` and not from `existUserProfileModel` but I don't know how to do it. This my code:

this my database:
[image: database1]
[image: database2]

```
public class UserProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 // created List from User Profile Model

private List<ExistUserProfileModel> existUserProfileModelList;
// define some Edit texts
private EditText profile_phone_ET, profile_FullName_ET, profile_Address_ET;
// define FireStore  
private FirebaseFirestore firestore;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);

    profile_phone_ET = findViewById(R.id.profile_Phone);
    profile_FullName_ET = findViewById(R.id.profile_FullName);
    profile_Address_ET = findViewById(R.id.profile_Address);
    firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    existUserProfileModelList = new ArrayList<>();

   firestore.collection("UserData").document().collection(profilePhone)
                                .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                        ExistUserProfileModel existUserProfileModel = document.toObject(ExistUserProfileModel.class);
                                        existUserProfileModelList.add(existUserProfileModel);

                                        profile_FullName_ET.setText(existUserProfileModel.getUserName());
                                        profile_Address_ET.setText(existUserProfileModel.getUserAddress());
                                    }
                                        Log.i("Size ", String.valueOf(existUserProfileModelList.size()));
                                }

                                else{
                                       Toast.makeText(UserProfileActivity.this, "Error" + task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: What exactly is null?

Comment: i created a model called ExistUserProfileModel, then define an Array List from it, and when i retrieve data from firestore and update the list by this data, i get that the array size still zero

Comment: Where in your code do you check that?

Comment: right after for statement in if condition, but i erase it.

Comment: Add it to your question to see it clearly, Please also edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: which database structure you want me to add i already copy and paste the code

Comment: The one that exists in the Firebase console. The and "UserData" collection and the "profilePhone" collection.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely in the query you are making:

```
firestore.collection("UserData").document().collection(profilePhone).get()
```

Since you are not passing any parameters in the `.document()`, meaning you are not selecting any "parent" `UserData` documents before selecting it's subdocuments.

As you can see in this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) you need to select which document you want to get passing it's docId. So this small change in your code will make it work as expected:

```
firestore.collection("UserData").document(docId).collection(profilePhone).get()
```

NOTE: How you are suppose to get this `docId` is up to the earlier stages of your app, if you do not have this available you might need to create some fields in this document to filter it out or get all documents and select the one you need.